# Find this symplectic transforming matrix

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, matrix-decomposition, bilinear-form, symplectic-linear-algebra

For some matrix $M$ of 2x2 block entries with diagonals

$$M_{jj} = \begin{bmatrix}0&a\\a&0\end{bmatrix},$$

where $a$ is a real constant, and with off diagonal elements

$$M_{jk} = \begin{bmatrix}0&b_{jk}\\b_{jk}^*&0\end{bmatrix},$$

where $j, k$ are integers ranging between 1 and $n$. Hence the dimensions of $M$ is $2n$x$2n$. How can I find the transforming simplectic matrix $S$ which relates $M$ to the block diagonal matrix $N$, where the diagonal elements are

$$N_{jj} = \begin{bmatrix}0&c_j\\c_j&0\end{bmatrix}.$$ Specifically, how can I find $S$ such that

$$M = S^\top N S$$

Comment: If it makes sense maybe you can do $S^T N^{T/2} N^{1/2} S = (N^{1/2}S)^T(N^{1/2}S) = M$

Comment: @mathreadler, I'm not sure how this would help?